# Alize: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, speech

I am getting below error message while verifying Speaker using Alize tool kit

```
(ComputeTest) No Channel Compensation
Compute Test, Decime mode[1] File Mode- 1 LLR by file
[ IndexOutOfBoundsException 0x8f762e0 ]
message   = ""
source file = Object.cpp
line number = 146
index 0 >= limit 0
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Which programming language you are using? Add it as a tag. And please show us the code that produces the above error message.

Comment: I m using c++ programming language.I m using alize took kit for speaker recognition.once training done to verify speaker voice  I am getting abovr mentioned error.I m receiving error from alize open source tool kit.